# Nuxt.js Generated Static Site Not Falling to 404 on Firebase Hosting but works on Localhost

Tags: nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

Nuxtjs Version: 2.14.5

I've recently prerendered my nuxtjs website with the following settings in nuxt.config.js using nuxt generate.

```
export default {
  ssr: true,
  target: 'static',
  generate: {
    fallback: true,
    exclude: [
      '/preview'
    ],
    routes() {
      return getRoutes();
    }
  },
```

404.html appears in my /dist folder

On localhost (running nuxt start), whenever I go to a bad link, the 404 page shows up as intended.

I have deployed my static site to Firebase Hosting, and now when I go to a bad link, the 404 page does not show up, instead, I am directed to a slightly horrible looking home page.

Does anyone know why this is the case or anything I can look in to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution,
Basically it has to do with the firebase.json file and rewrites.
As a fully static site, the javascript doesn't handle the navigation, because the user makes direct requests to firebase for the specific page's html file.
So, we need to set up a rewrite that specifies that "for all links that are broken, serve 404.html"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

In Firebase.json,

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/404.html"
      }
    ]
```

The destination needs to be set to 404.html and that is it!